# Can't generate IPA on iOS PROJECT

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ipa

I updated the VS to version 16.9.1 and updating the certificates, and now I can't generate an IPA (debug and release)

I have checked the option to build the IPA

I have deleted debug folder, close VS and reopen, but nothing...

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Alternatively you can try [Archive for Publishing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=macos#build-and-submit-your-app)

Comment: I can't archive @Ranjit, with Release and iPhone selected in the configurations, VS tells me that "the selected device does not support archiving"

Comment: There should be an option called "Generic Device" while selecting device. Please check with that option.